# JPanel.getBounds() unexpected returns 0

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, size

I have a class that extends from JFrame.
In its constructor I generate a JPanel:

```
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, contentPane.getBounds());
```

I thought with setContentPane, I would fill the whole available space in my JFrame. So it automatically sets the bounds of the JPanel.

I need to get the bounds of the JPanel, but getBounds() returns x = 0, y = 0, width = 0, height = 0. 
Other size related methods of the JPanel (like getWidth() etc.) also return 0. If I setBounds() of my JPanel explicit, the methods return my given values.

The curious thing about that is, that the setBackground fills the whole available space in my JFrame. So, the size of my JPanel must be exactly the size of my JFrame. But it doesn´t seem so.

Maybe this problem is caused by the layout manager, like most Container-related problems. But with a layout manager, I also get 0.

I think this is a very dumb question and can be easily solved, but I can´t figure out the problem.
I didn´t find an answer to this in the web, so hopefully didn´t dublicate some post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably as this is in your main `frame`s constructor you haven't called `setVisible(true)` on the main frame (the top level window) when you call `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`?

If so then the GUI components haven't yet been rendered, so they have bounds of [0, 0]. If you move `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` to after `setVisible` you'll get a dimension.

Alternatively you could call `pack` to lay things out. As per my comment below you would call `contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));` before you do this.

Comment: Yes, you were right. But I couldn´t call it after setVisible, because this moment is too late. So pack() sounds right, but if i call it, it sets my frame to a preferredSize and not to the size I preset. How to handle this?

Comment: @veritas. It depends so much on what your end-goal is, and what your Panel will contain, but one way will be to run `contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));` before calling `frame.pack()` on the top level window

Comment: @veritas What preset size? Because you've thrown away the layout manager for the `contentPane` it no longer has any ability to ascertain what the size it's content's might want in order to be displayed properly. Maybe you should enlighten us on what it is you are trying to achieve and why you would thrown away a core part of the API?

Comment: I'm with @MadProgrammer on this - I think you are describing [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so this question is pretty much unanswerable as it is currently phrased.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I´m developing an easy 2D game (Space Invaders). And I don´t see any benefit of using a layout manager. I could, of course, but I don´t know how the graphics, I will draw onto the JPanel would behave. Before the code above, i set the bounds of my JFrame. Also you should know that the size of my JFrame is immutable. (I know that a LayoutManager for mutable Frame sizes is very powerful). I need the bounds for game related restrictions.

Comment: @Then don't worry about.  Use `getPreferredSize` from the `JPanel` to return the size of the viewable area you want.  Use `JFrame#setResiazable` and `JFrame#pack` to make sure that the window is sized to meet the needs of your content pane.  When `paintComponent` is called, use `getWidth` and `getHeight` to determine current size of the panel.  You could also use a `ComponentListener` as well if you want to know the size BEFORE paint is called

Comment: @MadProgrammer you see a LayoutManager exceptionally not recommended :D A ComponentListener sounds suitable. paintComponent wouldn´t be a clean way, because it gets invoked by two Threads every ms, so i would request the dimension permanently. As I take it, I don´t need pack() if I use a ComponentListener. But which ComponentListener is recommended for this need? (Hidden, Moved, Resized or Shown?)

Comment: @MadProgrammer  `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(frameWidth, frameHeight));
  pack();
  
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "Frame: " + contentPane.getBounds());` This works for me!  Is this solution perfect? Because I want it to be.

Comment: @veritas. This is exactly what I suggested previously. If it does what you want then it is perfect, for your use case. Whether you call `setPreferredSize` on the top level window (the frame) or the panel is down to how you want to work out the math for the dimensions.

Comment: @veritas Remember two things, 1- You don't control the paint process, so all painting needs to be done within the context of the paint components; 2- Swing is not thread safe, make sure anything that the paint method might rly on is synchronised so that you don't end up with dirty paints. Based on you're needs, you're after the resized event. You could also delay starting your threads until the shown and resized events occur...setPreferredSize can also have undesirable side effects, simply beware of it...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, I think I´ve got the basic concepts of developing simple 2D games with Swing.I know there are various concepts and I don´t use the most mature one. I use two tickers. One triggers animations every 70ms and the other cares about the running of the game and triggers every 10ms. I know that this is sufficient for a space invaders game. For the future I´m thinking of doing it more professional, like every graphic extends from jcomponent and has a ticker etc. What gui api would you suggest for professional 2D games like flappy bird (as desktop application)?

Comment: @MadProgrammer ... and what do you mean by "setPreferredSize can also have undesirable side effects"?

Answer (score 3):

> The curious thing about that is, that the setBackground fills the whole available space in my JFrame. So, the size of my JPanel must be exactly the size of my JFrame. But it doesn´t seem so.

Actually no, the content pane will be smaller then the frame, because it's contained within the frame decorations. That means the viewable space is the size of the window - the size of the decorations.

Also, a component won't be painted until its sized beyond 0x0

Before the `contentPane` can know how big it will be, it needs to be laid out by it's parent container.  In order for the parent container to lay out the child container(s), it needs to know the size they might like to be.

As you say, this is related to the layout managers, in order for container to know how big it can be, it needs to know how much space it's parent container will give it.

> Maybe this problem is caused by the layout manager, like most Container-related problems. But with a layout manager, I also get 0.

A container, even under the management of a layout manager, won't be assigned a size until the parent container is sized appropriately.

While there are several ways to overcome this, the question becomes why? The fact that you're setting the contentPane's layout manager to null is worrisome and would suggest that you're now going to need to reinvent the wheel and replace the job that the layout managers do for you anyway.

I would suggest calling `pack` before you try and get the component size, but, again, because you've negated the layout manager, this won't result in a value you would be happy with...